# Convert mysql to laravel 5 eloquent (left join with select)

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I am stuck at rewriting mysql query to laravel eloquent.

```
LEFT JOIN `products_options` ON `products_options`.`id` = (
        SELECT products_options.id FROM products_options WHERE 1
        AND products_options.product_id = products.id 
        AND products_options.color = $color
    )
```

Any help?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use relations and eager loading.

Comment: That doesn't look like a full query.

Comment: That query is joining two of the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate that query use the following

```
$products = DB::table ('product_options')
    ->leftJoin ('products', 'product_options.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->where('product_options.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->where('product_options.color', '=', $color)->get();
```

Your query looks a little off but this is it replicated using the eloquent query builder. Don't forget to reference DB in your controller or model